# Proving that the horizontal composition of natural transformations is a natural transformation

Tags: category-theory, natural-transformations

Is there an easy way to prove that the horizontal composition of natural transformations is a natural transformation?

To fix the notation, here is part of [Leinster's textbook](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf):

[image]

Suppose $f:A\to A'$ is an arrow in $\mathscr A$. We need to show that $$(\alpha'\ast\alpha)_{A'}\circ (F'\circ F)(f)=(G'\circ G)(f)\circ (\alpha'\ast \alpha)_A$$

I tried substituting both expressions from the definition of $(\alpha'\ast\alpha)_{A'}$ (and also of $(\alpha'\ast \alpha)_A$), but it's not clear how to simplify either of them.

---

(the vertical arrows are $\alpha_A$ and $\alpha_{A'}$)
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
F(A) @>{F(f)}>> F(A');\\
@VVV @VVV \\
G(A) @>{G(f)}>> G(A');
\end{CD}$$

Comment: Draw the diagrams of each of the natural transformations and link them together. The algebra will fall out.

Comment: @JohnDouma I can draw the diagram for $\alpha$, but to draw a diagram for $\alpha'$, I need an object of $\mathscr A'$, which I don't have. I only have two objects ($A$ and $A'$) of $\mathscr A$. I can take their images either under $F$ or under $G$, but I don't see how to link the diagrams.

Comment: You have three categories $A$, $B$ and $C$ and two pairs of functors between each of $A$ and $B$ and $B$ and $C$. For each of the categories the diagrams have to work for all objects and all morphisms so you can just choose an object from each of the three categories.

Comment: @JohnDouma I've added the first diagram to the question. To join it with a second diagram, the second diagram must either have $G(A)\to G(A')$ on top (if we join the diagrams vertically) or $F(A')\to G(A')$ on the left (if we join them horizontally). But the natural diagram for $\alpha'$ has neither of these properties.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation The Wiki has a section on operations with natural transformations that has what you need.

Comment: @JohnDouma The Wikipedia article doesn't contain any information that is not present in Leinster. It only has definitions, but it doesn't make it clear why the horizontal composition is a natural transformation. If you're referring to the interchange law for horizontal and vertical composition, I don't know how this can be helpful. (Leinster also writes about it, but after he claims that the horizontal composition is a natural transformation, from which I assume that the proof shouldn't appeal to this fact.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix an arrow $f : A \to B$ in $\mathcal{A}$.

By the naturality of $\alpha$, we recover the following (commutative) diagram.

$\begin{CD} 
FA @>Ff>> FB\\
@VV\alpha_AV @VV\alpha_BV\\
GA @>Gf>> GB
\end{CD}$

Now we eventually want to have a diagram involving $F'F$, so let's hit the diagram with $F'$. Recall functors preserve commutative diagrams, so the following still commutes.

$\begin{CD}
F'FA @>F'Ff>> F'FB\\
@VVF'\alpha_AV @VVF'\alpha_BV\\
F'GA @>F'Gf>> F'GB
\end{CD}$

We also want $G'G$ to be in the picture somewhere, and we know how to turn an $F'$ into a $G'$, so...

$\begin{CD}
F'FA @>F'Ff>> F'FB\\
@VVF'\alpha_AV @VVF'\alpha_BV\\
F'GA @>F'Gf>> F'GB\\
@VV\alpha'_{GA}V @VV\alpha'_{GB}V\\
G'GA @>G'Gf>> G'GB
\end{CD}$

Since the top and bottom squares both commute, it is a simple exercise to show the outer square does too.

Thus we obtain a commutative diagram:

$\begin{CD}
F'FA @>F'Ff>> F'FB\\
@VV\alpha'_{GA} \circ F'\alpha_AV @VV\alpha'_{GB} \circ F'\alpha_BV\\
G'GA @>G'Gf>> G'GB
\end{CD}$

But recall (as your question mentions) 
$(\alpha' * \alpha)_A = \alpha'_{GA} \circ F' \alpha_A$.

Renaming our diagram using this definition gives:

$\begin{CD}
F'FA @>F'Ff>> F'FB\\
@VV(\alpha' * \alpha)_AV @VV(\alpha' * \alpha)_BV\\
G'GA @>G'Gf>> G'GB
\end{CD}$

Since the same argument works for any $A,B,f$, this square witnesses the naturality of $\alpha' * \alpha$.

---

As is often the case in category theory, we found this argument by doing the only thing available to us. We wanted a diagram of a certain type, and at each step there was really only one choice. Unfortunately, this means that if we struggle to find the "one choice", we can really struggle to solve these kinds of problems! But that's ok, everyone has difficulty with these kinds of arguments, but we all become comfortable with them in time.

---

I hope this helps ^_^